# JQuery. how do I create nested buttons with well defined onclick action (MODIFIED)

Tags: jquery

For my little project (which involves nested forms), it seems that I need something as below. I am not sure how to pass parameters `x` and `y` as to have nested buttons. What I need is that a nested button 'knows' under which outer button is. How do I achieve that? Is there a way to write something like `$(".add_field_button_sub_"+x+"")`?

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>

<title> test </title>


<script src="jquery-3.2.0.js" type="text/javascript">  </script>  

<script  type="text/javascript"> 


$(document).ready(function() {
    var wrapper         = $(".input_fields_wrap"); 

    var x = 0; //initial text box count
    $(".add_field_button").click(function(e){ 

  if(x < 10){
 $( "<div><div>Hello! ("+x+")</div><div><button class=\"add_field_button_sub_"+x+"\">Sub Button "+x+"</button></div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( '.add_field_button' );

 var y = 0; //initial text box count
 $(".add_field_button_sub_"+x+"").click(function(e){ 
 if(y < 10){
 $( "<div><div>Hello Sub! ("+x+"."+y+")</div><br><a href=\"#\" class=\"remove_field\">Remove</a></div><hr>" ).insertBefore( ".add_field_button_sub_"+x+"" );
y++;
}
    });

x++; 
}
    });

    $(wrapper).on("click",".remove_field", function(e){ //user click on remove text
        e.preventDefault(); $(this).parent('div').remove();
    })
}); </script>  


</head>
<body>
<h3>TEST</h3> </br>

<div class="input_fields_wrap">
    <button class="add_field_button">Fonti</button>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The click handler can only be attached to the button after it has been added to the DOM.

Comment: ok, thanks. How do I do so?

Comment: I think I got it (I have already tried, but it did not work, maybe I have a typo somewhere else). Hope it helps some other newbie.

Comment: also you could try live-bindings.

Comment: If you want to attach an event to a created button use `$(document).on('.thebutton','click',function() { ... });`

Comment: @mario Sorry, I commented right before I left for work. Looks like you got it though, so good job!